Making an add-on - Notification system setup
I am trying my hands on my first add-on for blender. It currently creates incremental saves of a project into a predetermined location in a predetermined interval. As of right now the backup notifications are handled this way:
bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(lambda self, context: self.layout.label(text=f"Backup saved: {backup_name}"), title="Backup", icon='INFO')

Which creates a pop-up at the cursor location preventing any work until acknowledged. My preferred goal for this would be to be a non-intrusive notification similar to what you get when pressing ⇧ Shift + S but all attempts I tried getting this to work yielded no promising results. From what I understand these notifications are reserved for actions by the user and not by the system. I can create a button that prints "success" at the bottom, but getting the system itself to use this notification method seems to be a different thing.
Here is the script I used to get the success button working (code block is not working, if anyone smarter than me can fix that, you are very welcome to do so):
bl_info = {
    "name": "Success on Save Add-on",
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "category": "Object",
    "description": "Sends a success message to the status bar whenever a .blend file is saved"
}

import bpy

def save_success_handler(dummy):
    """Function called after saving a .blend file"""
    bpy.ops.wm.report_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT', message="Success")

class ReportOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator to display a custom message in the status bar"""
    bl_idname = "wm.report_operator"
    bl_label = "Show Success"

    message: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.report({'INFO'}, self.message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ReportOperator)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.append(save_success_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ReportOperator)
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.remove(save_success_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Checking a question recommended to me from 2.7x times did not appear effective, I do not exempt me from being too dense to get it, coding is not my strong suit, but from where I am standing here, the answers provided did not help.
If anyone has some insight on how to get such a notification going I'd highly appreciate to hear from you. Thanks in advance.

Does this answer the question? If not, please [edit] your question to better explain what you are missing, it will queue it up for reopening.

This to me seems fairly outdated, trying the solutions provided did not yield any useful results. I am not sure how to better explain. Open up Blender, press ctrl S, see the bottom blue colored notification? That style of notification I am trying to achieve when a backup triggers. Instead what I currently have is a pop-up that halts every operation done in viewport.

@Deven The "See the bottom blue colored notification" is literally done with the Operator.report() method. That is how you do it. Docs

@jakemoyo that I also got, but every time I try to implement that to be not triggered by user, but by the system it fails and the timer does no longer reset.
